# Dealing with multiple output results in UPSERT query [SQL]

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do an update query in which a single row the table is updated and, if nothing has matched and updated, a new row is inserted. In each case, I need the query to return the ID of the inserted row.

The issue I'm having is this query is returning 2 separate results when the insert case is reached, one for each output (the first empty, the second containing the ID). I'm running this query using SQL Alchemy on python and I'm only able to see the first result, which is empty.

```
UPDATE [Rights]
    SET accessLevel = :access_level
    OUTPUT inserted.rightsID
    WHERE principal = :principal and [function] = :function
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO Rights(principal, [function], accessLevel)
        OUTPUT inserted.rightsID
        VALUES(:principal, :function, :access_level)
```

And I'm calling it like so:

`inserted_right_id = session.execute(sql_rights_update, right).fetchall()`

Can anyone recommend a way of changing the query so that I can still use the UPSERT method, but only receive one of the IDs? I was considering storing the OUTPUT values into a table and returning that, or wrapping the whole thing in a select but hopefully there's something more elegant out there.

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling quite dumb. I simply added a

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Rights WHERE principal = :principal and [function] = :function)
    UPDATE ...
ELSE
    INSERT ...
```